# NumericTextBox Kendo UI for Angular2 with custom IntlService

Tags: internationalization, kendo-ui-angular2

I have taken latest RC0 of Kendo UI for Angular2. It's docs mentions use of Internationalization service. I have created custom IntlService and configured it's provider in my App Module. In the component if I use the IntlService dependency then my custom service is invoked, but the NumericTextBox is not calling my service. What's wrong in the following code?

MyIntlService.ts

```
import { CldrIntlService } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyIntlService extends CldrIntlService {         
        constructor() {
            super("en-US");
            console.info('From MyIntlService ctor');
        }
        formatNumber(value: number, format: string| NumberFormatOptions){
            const result = super.formatNumber(value,format);
            console.log('In MyIntlService formatNumber');
            return result;
        }  
}
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, InputsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
   providers:    [{
     provide: IntlService,
     useClass: MyIntlService
   }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component

```
export class AppComponent  { 
  constructor(private intl: IntlService) {
      console.log( " From AppComponent " +  intl.formatNumber(42, "c"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can file an issue in the [GitHub repository ↗](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues). Providing a runnable example demonstrating the issue will be appreciated.